# Casting pointers in expressions?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to construct a GraphicsDevice in XNA 4.0 from an already existing device.
To do this I'm trying to call the non public constructor GraphicsDevice(IDirect3DDevice9* pInterface, GraphicsDevice pDevice).
Note that it takes a pointer, which is causing me a lot of problems.

```
 ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(GraphicsDevice).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];
 ParameterInfo[] paramsInfo = ctor.GetParameters();

 var args = new Expression[]
    {
     Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(pointer), typeof(IntPtr).GetMethod("ToPointer")), paramsInfo[0].ParameterType), 
     Expression.Constant(null, typeof(GraphicsDevice)),
    };

 NewExpression newExp = Expression.New(ctor, args);

 LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<GraphicsDevice>), newExp);

 var compiled = (Func<GraphicsDevice>)lambda.Compile();
 GraphicsDevice device = compiled();
 return device;
```

The problem occurs on this line, where an exception is thrown:

```
Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(pointer), typeof(IntPtr).GetMethod("ToPointer")), paramsInfo[0].ParameterType),
```

The exception thrown is:

> No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Void*' and 'IDirect3DDevice9*'.

Is there any way to circumvent this? I already tried various other methods with Pointer.Box, Activator and manually invoking the constructor.

Comment: Note that if I use TypeAs instead of Convert, it compiles it fine.
In this line: GraphicsDevice device = compiled();
It throws the exception "Operation could destabilize the runtime.".

Comment: what is a pointer? where do you initiate it?

Comment: Sorry, 'pointer' is of type IntPtr (the code field handles { and } badly (atleast in the preview)) The method signature is:
GraphicsDevice CreateFromPointer(IntPtr pointer)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Where did the existing device come from?

Comment: Why do you need to create a separate GraphicsDevice? Does the default device not contain perform what you need?

Comment: I'm guessing he has an existing D3D device that was not created by XNA and he wants to use it as a GraphicsDevice. Seems like this should be possible, but of course any solution will be unreliable against future versions of XNA (although that may not be a concern for him).

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the constructor to actually run with the following code, however it still dies with a null reference exception inside the internal CreateHelperClasses method. I don't think this constructor is used for what you think it is. I'm not sure what you're trying to do is actually possible unfortunately.

```
 unsafe
        {
           // this seems to always be null
           GraphicsDevice parent = (GraphicsDevice)typeof(GraphicsDevice).GetField("_parent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(oldDevice);

           IntPtr pInterface = new IntPtr(Pointer.Unbox(typeof(GraphicsDevice).GetField("pComPtr", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(oldDevice)));               

           ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(GraphicsDevice).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];

           GraphicsDevice newDevice = (GraphicsDevice)ci.Invoke(new object[] { pInterface, parent });
        }
```